# Programmatically query for legal crypto key sizes on Android

Tags: android, cryptography, bouncycastle

I want to programmatically enumerate the allowed key sizes for a given Cipher. Is there an API to do this?
(I'm on Android, using the bouncycastle built into it).

Comment: <overly-complicated-way>You could make a request to Wikipedia, parse the page of the cipher and extract the "Key sizes" value from the table (which is available for all common ciphers).</overly-complicated-way>

Comment: No thanks. I'd sooner just hard-code the expected result for each cipher. But as these answers vary by implementation, version, and platform, I'd rather query at runtime.

Comment: Why? Some ciphers such as Blowfish allow variable sized keys. You would not want a user to be confronted with that right? Or with a single DES variant of 64 bits (56 effective)?

Comment: This isn't about exposing the option to the end user. And if Blowfish allows variable sized keys, that's exactly why I want to be able to query it to determine what's allowed. I'm writing a crypto library (PCLCrypto, to be exact) that wraps many other platforms' crypto. All other platforms PCLCrypto supports offer a way to enumerate the key sizes allowed, which is useful when as a consumer of this library you want to explore what the options are instead of getting bad key size exceptions. Android/BC is holding me back from knowing offering functionality on the last platform.

Comment: Android is one thing and Bouncycastle is another, though I think the answer is no for both. Technically the bouncycastle classes (org.bouncycastle.*) are only accessible indirectly via the JCE engines and not directly.

Comment: Thanks, @JamesKPolk. I thought Android's crypto was implemented by BouncyCastle itself (albeit an old subset rather than a complete modern one). So to be clear, I'm using C# and Mono.Android and the Javax.Crypto.Cipher class.

Comment: Oh, C#. Sorry, I didn't realize that. I don't know how that runtime is implemented for Android.

Comment: I found evidence that Android's crypto is indeed based on BouncyCastle: See the discussion here http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BJA-543

Answer (score 0):

Edward Ned Harvey provided this answer on a mailing list:

> If it's a .NET cipher, you can use the LegalKeySizes property
>
> If it's a BouncyCastle derivative of IBlockCipher, there is no such analogous property of IBlockCipher. In fact, by looking at AESFastEngine, the only time the key size seems to be checked is during GenerateWorkingKey(), which is called by Init(). There, it's hard-coded in a private method, to check the Key length, must be 128, 192, or 256. Based on this, I'd say there is no programmatic way, nor even an enum you could use.

Comment: You could make a feature request to the Bouncycastle dev team to add this.

Comment: Yes, I'm in progress of sending an email to the right DL now. However that won't help me for a long while, since PCLCrypto targets whatever crypto is in rather old versions of Android.